# Reduce results in an error for a polynomial with real (non-integer) coefficients

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, reduce, polynomial-math

In Mathematica, I tried to check some condition for a polynomial, whose parameters change in a range. My calculations are 5th order but I made a simple one to show my needs.

When I create a polynomial, which has integers as parameter, I use `Reduce` and it gives me right answer.

But when I use real numbers in the polynomial, `Reduce` doesn't work and gives this error:

> Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.

Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Looks fine to me... What's the answer that you were expecting?

Comment: I expect to not to see "Reduce: ratnz" error. That makes me curious about the result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Reduce::ratnz` message is **not** an error, but a warning message. If you click on the `More` link or `>>`, whatever shows on your system, it'll take you to the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/message/Reduce/ratnz.html), which says:

> This message is often generated when the first argument in `Reduce` includes inexact numbers. [...] The warning message can be avoided by using only exact numbers in the input to `Reduce`

Now, if you're annoyed by the message, you can turn the message off using

```
Off[Reduce::ratnz]
```

which will turn off the warning for *all* further uses of `Reduce` or you can simply silence this operation using

```
Quiet@Reduce[...]
```

If you want to *avoid* the message, then as the documentation says, you'll have to use exact numbers. One way is to use `Rationalize`. For example:

```
x = 1.391 + 0.771 a;
Reduce[Rationalize[x] > 0 && 1 <= a <= 80, {a}]

Out[1]= 1 <= a <= 80
```

It gives you the output you desire, without a warning. There might be other ways depending on what exactly you're doing, but it's hard to say without knowing your exact expression. Hope this helped.